# firebase blaze firestore role

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, blaze

I have a blaze account on firestore. I'm trying to create a new firestore database and get this message:
"To manage Cloud Firestore, ask a project owner for the necessary permissions"

My roles:

- Cloud Storage for Firebase Admin,
- Firebase Admin
- Firebase Analytics Admin
- Firebase Develop Admin
- Firebase Rules System

What else should I have?

I'm attaching to 2 images:

[firestore page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBmZ4.png)

[IAM - my roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvyUH.png)

Thank you,
Geanni

Comment: I don't get your point here. What's the issue you're experiencing? Is your rule not working? Could you please give us more details, or maybe post your rule?

Comment: I added 2 images with the error on firestore and the IAM rules. The problem is that I don't have the option to create the database, I see a message asking to have additional permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roles you've listed give you read/write access to the various Firebase services, but not the ability to add and remove them entirely from a project - that permission comes from Google Cloud itself.

The [basic IAM roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-basic) define an `Owner` role that contains the needed permissions, but this is probably not what you are looking for.

At a more fine-tuned level, you should be able to use `roles/datastore.owner` to grant the ability to provision a Firestore database (Firestore is a layer on top of Datastore). That should be all you would need, but you might also need to consider `roles/appengine.appAdmin` too.

Relevant links:

- [Datastore IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam#permissions)
- [Firebase documentation on IAM permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#firestore).

Comment: You made some light on my problem about this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-category), you need the follow role:

```
Firebase Develop Admin - roles/firebase.developAdmin
```

Comment: Right, I already see have this role, but still get the error this is my problem. Please look on the image attached to the initial question.